# Middleware for update document with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What is the best option to update a document with mongoosejs? Function Find and save or update? Update don't make pre("validate") or pre("save") of schema middlewares.

Find and save:

```
User.findById(userId, fields, options, function(err, userResult){

    if(err){
      return callback(err);
    }

    userResult.age = 15;

    userResult.save();

    callback(null, userResult);

});
```

update:

```
User.update(filter, update, options, callback);
```

And if you update more than one document? I need use update, but this don't make middlewares...

Comment: Is your question how to run mongoose middleware befire update. `Schema.pre('update')` should work

Comment: @AndreasHultgren this dosn't work. This middleware not's exists

Comment: My mistake then. I was under the impression that mongoose uses [hooks](https://github.com/bnoguchi/hooks-js/) and thus should be able to support .pre on any method.

Comment: But ¿Why this not its supported yet? maybe the single update flow or multiple update flow will be different? Its extrange, and mongoose support seems OFF

Comment: I would guess it will never be supported because there can be no `this` when updating. In pre save you can modify a document through `this.property`, but that doesn't exist when updating since the document won't be fetched. Btw, one option would be to set your own `Schema.statics.update`.